# Contradiction with rectangular slab in uniform $B$ field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

I am considering a case of a rectangular slab of linear magnetic and insulating material (with non-zero magnetic susceptibility $\chi$) in a uniform magnetic field and I am experiencing a contradiction.

If I use that the parallel component of $H$ is conserved (for no surface free current) then I obtain $H_{in}=H_{ext}$ and therefore $B_{in}=\mu_0 (1+\chi) H_{ext}$ but if I use that the perpendicular component of B is conserved then I get $B_{in}=B_{ext}=\mu_0 H_{ext}$.

These conditions can only both be true if $\chi=0$ But this is a contradiction.

My only thoughts are the non-smooth corners of the rectangle could break things since there is no well defined parallel or perpendicular directions at those points and so edge effects may not be able to be neglected.

[image]

Comment: Don't forget the poles induced at the two end plates of the slab that are perpendicular to the external field. These poles are in opposition to $B_{ext}$ and will reduce its value near them. Unless this is a thin and long cylindrical rod the poles cannot be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the biggest point I was forgetting is that only the *net* B field perpendicular component is conserved, and in this case there will be some outward *induced* B field from the magnetic material so eventhough $B_{perpendicular}$ is conserved over the boundary, $B_{perpendicular} \neq B_{ext}$ unless the material does not produce any induced B field (and thus $\chi = 0$ exactly as obtained from the maths.